# Android xml Table Layout

Tags: android, xml, tablelayout

So I'm trying to create a table that looks something like this:

```
shrimp: 12pc $10.99   24pc $18.99

scallops: 10pc $11.99   15pc $14.99
```

...etc

but somethings wrong with my code that is making the first column (for example `shrimp`) take most of the screen space and the count and price end up squished on the right side of the screen.

```
 <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_conent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Shrimp:" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="12pc - $10.99" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="24pc - $18.99" />
    </TableRow>
```

Can someone tell what I have wrong here? I tried playing around with the layout width and heights but the only way I can get it to look the way I want is if I type something wrong in the layout width for the first columns. It looks the way I want that way but I get a compiler error if I do so.

Comment: All TextViews: change `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` to `android:layout_width="0dp"` That's the way **weight** works.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of layout_weight attribute, try to remove it, and add some space between your TextViews.

Then it will be such as you need.